# RevMob callbacks don't work but ads still show (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, revmob

I'm using the Unity SDK for RevMob, and it seems to show ads just fine when I call revmob.ShowFullscreen(), but I'm not getting any callback functionality at all. Is this an issue with RevMob? I'm using version 7.2.7 of the SDK.

Before anyone asks, yes I made sure to implement the IRevMobListener interface fully with Debug.Log() calls in each one.